# Why I cannot create an invoice from an completed order

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice, sales-order

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and I have a problem with some orders. They are paid by CC and the order is now Completed but I can not create an Invoice. I can not see the invoice button on Order and I can not invoice it Pro-grammatically too. I tried to invoice it with a custom module that I created but still it is blocked on $order->canInvoice().

How can I force it to create or at least how can I see the detailed error?

I am printing out the caught $e and it says data_invalid that is all.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php say on what happens in `$order->canInvoice();` line 603. To summarize:

- It must NOT have an `unhold` or `invoice` action flag. Apparently this could be reversed by setting all flags off:

  ```
      $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_CANCEL, false);
      $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_HOLD, false);
      $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_UNHOLD, false);
      $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_EDIT, false);
      $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_CREDITMEMO, false);
      $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_INVOICE, false);
      $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_REORDER, false);
      $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_SHIP, false);
      $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_COMMENT, false);
      $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_PRODUCTS_PERMISSION_DENIED, false);
  ```
- It should NOT be of the following status: `canceled`, `complete`, `payment_review`, `holded` or `closed`. (Programatically resetting status to `new` can get you out of this).
- It should NOT have been partially invoiced yet. Which can mean to delete all invoices related to this order.
- For each items in the orders, quantity invoiced should be set to zero, like so:

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $item->setData('qty_invoiced', 0);
}
```

I admit it's a pretty long list to just to get that pesky `Invoice` button back.

```
public function canInvoice()
{
    if ($this->canUnhold() || $this->isPaymentReview()) {
        return false;
    }
    $state = $this->getState();
    if ($this->isCanceled() || $state === self::STATE_COMPLETE || $state === self::STATE_CLOSED) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_INVOICE) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getQtyToInvoice()>0 && !$item->getLockedDoInvoice()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ardee, I tried all the code snippets published about that issue but at the end I got no result. I gave up for now. But if you have a solution or any one please share. Since you are the only one who answered I am accepting this answer.

Comment: You  need to add ->save(); after ('qty_invoiced',0) otherwise it's perfect!

Comment: @CntkCtn you just have to love Magento, don't you. I'm so glad I'm not doing it anymore!!

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to create invoice in the [inchoo blog](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-orders/automatically-invoice-ship-complete-order-in-magento/).Ill add this as an answer if we search on google redirected to this question.

```
if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
   $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Inchoo_Invoicer: Order cannot be invoiced.', false);
   $order->save();  
 }

//START Handle Invoice
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();

$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
$invoice->register();

$invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(false);          
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
$order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically INVOICED by Inchoo_Invoicer.', false);

$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                ->addObject($invoice)
                ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

$transactionSave->save();
```

Hope this will help some one in future.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to change the order status from completed to pending, then I have created an invoice. Hope this helps others.